# REGEXP_REPLACE in post_contet

Tags: sql, regex, post-content

So, basically, I want to remove trailing slashes from specific domain urls. For example: `https://www.example.com/here/postname/`
into `https://www.example.com/here/postname`

I have 10.4.21-MariaDB which should support REGEXP_REPLACE function.

This is my query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '(http\S+)\/(\s|$)', '$1');
```

or this one more specifically:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '(https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/here\/\S+)\/(\s|$)', '$1');
```

which according to regular expressions should work:
https://regex101.com/r/slLbgg/1

What am I doing wrong?

Any kind of help is appreciated! :)

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: Try `\\1` instead of `$1`, see eg https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if someone in the future also needs something like this,
I found the solution after some time of playing with regular expressions.

This worked for me:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`post_content`, 'https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/magazin\/(.*?)\/">', 'https://www.example.com/magazin/\\1">');
```

Example in action can be seen here:
https://regex101.com/r/3ZPylJ/1

Hope it helps!

Smile to all :)